# AngularJS Bootstrap-datepicker popup shows incorrect date on first click

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am initilizing a model with a Date function and binding it to an input which has a datepicker.

```
<label>Begin Date</label>
<div class='input-group date'>
          <input ng-model="Main.BeginDate" class="form-control" onkeydown="return false" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" show-weeks="false" is-open="BeginDate" ng-focus="BeginDate=true" ng-click="BeginDate=true" min-date="Main.MinDate" required/>
          <span class="input-group-addon">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
 </div>
```

On first click, the datepicker shows the current date *even though the actual date is different*.
Then on clicking the input again, the datepicker-popup resets to the *correct date*.

I tried:

- Formatting date using `$filter`
- Custom `new Date()` function
- Removing `min-date` attribute

How do I get the popup to show the date bound to the model?

I am using:

- AngularJS v1.5.0
- Bootstrap v3.3.6
- Angular-ui-bootstrap Version: 0.13.4

First click ------>>>>>
[image]

Second click ----->>>>[image]

Answer (score 1):

I checked the situation and seems like the versions that you are using are somehow conflicting. If i use angular 1.4.9 or below and try your code all seems to work. Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/772TsNXxb32WvWUezAlQ?p=preview) to show you that. But as soon as I use angular 1.5.0 or above I face the same issue as you. You could use angular 1.4.9 and angular-ui-bootstrap 0.13.4 or upgrade your angular ui bootstrap version.

**index.html**

```
 <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="DateCtrl" style="padding:40px">
  <label>Begin Date</label>
<div class='input-group date'>
          <input ng-model="dt" class="form-control" onkeydown="return false" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" show-weeks="false" is-open="BeginDateOpen" ng-focus="BeginDateOpen=true" ng-click="BeginDateOpen=true" min-date="Main.MinDate" required/>
          <span class="input-group-addon">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
 </div>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**example.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('app').controller('DateCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.today = function(){
  $scope.dt = new Date(1998,1,5)
}
$scope.today();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I cannot change Angular below 1.5 because other libraries are dependent on that version. I did try to change UI-bootstrap from 0.13.4 to 1.0.0 or even 2.0.1. But the popup was never showing up. https://plnkr.co/edit/15euZAV2vERLC6KS6Hgf .But I found another way to fix it. I have added the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Amit, the issue seems to be because of the incompatibilities between the versions of the libraries.

Based on the bug mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/5081), the solution to add atttribute init-date worked.

```
<input ng-model="dt" class="form-control" 
        onkeydown="return false" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" show-weeks="false" 
        is-open="BeginDateOpen" ng-focus="BeginDateOpen=true" ng-click="BeginDateOpen=true" 
        min-date="Main.MinDate" required
        init-date="dt"/>
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/A4Z7pfglhQW62d1gNTuK)